# Python counting votes in election and combining score with names [List]

Tags: python, list

I have a problem to solve. I need to write a program which takes candidate names from the user and their number of votes received and the program should output each candidate’s name, the votes received by that candidate and the percentage of the total votes received by the candidate. The program should also output the winner of the election, the person with the least votes and the average amount of votes. I have done this so far but I don't how to combine names with appropriate vote numbers.

```
from statistics import mean
vote_list = []
votes_numbers = []

for i in range(5):
    candidate = input("Enter the name of the candidate:")
    vote_list.append(candidate)
    number_votes = int(input('Enter the number of votes:'))
    votes_numbers.append(number_votes)
print(vote_list)
print(votes_numbers)

for x, y in zip(vote_list, votes_numbers):
    print(x, y)


total_votes = sum(votes_numbers)
max_votes = max(votes_numbers)
winner_index = votes_numbers.index(max_votes)
winner_name = vote_list[winner_index]

print(winner_name)
print(mean(votes_numbers))
print(max(votes_numbers))
```

Comment: Can you add expected input and output?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Expected input from the user is five candidates names and their number of votes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing your data structure from list to dictionary would allow you to keep track of the input data in an easier way.

That would also be handy in case of other / future calculations:

```
from statistics import mean

votes = {}

for i in range(5):
    candidate = input("Enter the name of the candidate:")
    number_votes = int(input('Enter the number of votes:'))
    votes[candidate] = number_votes

total_votes = sum(votes.values())
max_votes = max(votes.values())

for key, value in votes.items():
    if value == max_votes:
        winner_name = key
        break

print("{} is the winner with a total of {} votes".format(winner_name, max_votes))
```

**Edit - New version after reading the List requirement**

I've read in comments that you want to just use lists.
Even if this approach can seem simpler for a beginner I strongly suggest to learn and understand also dictionaries.

In any case I understood your requirement and here's a solution just using lists.
As you can see a possible solution is - assuming that both list will have same lenght - that if, for example, the max vote index is 3 we will find the winner's name also in index 3 of the candidates list.

I made the code verbose so that it will be easier to understand and tweak it:

```
from statistics import mean

candidates = []
votes_received = []

for i in range(5):
    candidate = raw_input("Enter the name of the candidate:")
    number_votes = int(raw_input('Enter the number of votes:'))
    candidates.append(candidate)
    votes_received.append(number_votes)

total_votes = sum(votes_received)
votes_received_by_winner = max(votes_received)
index_of_the_winner_name = votes_received.index(votes_received_by_winner)
winner_name = candidates[index_of_the_winner_name]

print("{} is the winner with a total of {} votes".format(winner_name, votes_received_by_winner))
```

Comment: Hi @andre!
I've read your requirement about just using lists and I've updated my answer.

Please remember to upvote it and / or mark it as final answer if you found it useful.

Answer (score 1):

you could use a dictionary to associate the votes with candidates and do it as follows:

```
from statistics import mean
candidate_votes = {}

for i in range(5):
    candidate = input("Enter the name of the candidate:")
    number_votes = int(input('Enter the number of votes:'))
    candidate_votes[candidate] = number_votes

votes = list(candidate_votes.values())

max_votes_index = votes.index(max(votes))

candidates = list(candidate_votes.keys())

winner_candid_index = candidates[max_votes_index]

print("Winner is ", candidates[max_votes_index])
print("average of votes are ", mean(votes))
print("The winner ",candidates[max_votes_index], ' had ',votes[max_votes_index], ' 
number of votes.')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are just looking to combine the winner name and votes in a print statement use format strings as in:

```
print("{} is the winner with  {} number of votes".format(winner_name,max(votes_numbers)))
```

Comment: How could we combine candidate name with appropriate vote number and print possibly using only lists?

Comment: I am sorry Andre but I don't quite get what you mean by only lists. Are you looking to print all candidate names and votes??